# pgfgantt title spacing

Tags: spacing, pgfgantt

I have the code below which produces the titles as in the attached image.

As you can see the month names are squashed, how can i fix this please?

Thanks.

```
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]

\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
bar/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!20},
compress calendar
]{2016-06}{2018-09}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month, month=shortname} \\
  \ganttbar{Task1}{2016-06}{2018-07} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

[image]

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example increase the `x unit` of the chart a little bit from its default `0.5cm`, or reduce the font size of the title using `title font style=\tiny`. Also note that you do not need to put the `ganttchart` environment in a `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
x unit=0.7cm,
hgrid,
vgrid,
time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
bar/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!20},
compress calendar
]{2016-06}{2018-09}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month, month=shortname} \\
  \ganttbar{Task1}{2016-06}{2018-07} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
title label font={\tiny},
bar/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!20},
compress calendar
]{2016-06}{2018-09}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month, month=shortname} \\
  \ganttbar{Task1}{2016-06}{2018-07} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]